# How to add several classes to ul list

Tags: jquery, list, class, addclass, html-lists

How can I add several classes to ul list? I don't want to add it to every li items but just some of them.

**EDIT:**

I want to add classes with jQuery. Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>something1</li>
    <li>something2</li>
    <li>something3</li>
    <li>something4</li>
    <li>something5</li>
</ul>
```

And now I want to add class every li after the second one (3rd, 4th and 5th li element). I know how to add class but how can i make it to repeat in each li. Thats my problem really.

Comment: It seems that what you really ask is "is there a jQuery selector to select the odd list items after the 3rd?".  Maybe you should post another question for that...

Answer (score 1):

Well, to add 3 classes to every `li` in a `ul`, you'd do:

```
$("#myUl > li").addClass("class1 class2 class3");
```

Since you don't specify any criteria for the `li` elements you want to get the additional classes, I'm forced to guess:

```
$("#myUl > li:even").addClass("class1 class2 class3");
```

That will add the three classes to every other `li` (the even numbered elements in a zero-indexed array, to be more precise).

Good luck.

Comment: Ah well, here's better explanition:

<ul>
<li>something1</li>
<li>something2</li>
<li>something3</li>
<li>something4</li>
<li>something5</li>
</ul>

And now I want to add class every li after the second one (3rd, 4th and 5th li element). I know how to add class but how can i make it to repeat in each li. Thats my problem really.

Comment: You should add this comment as part of your question and format the code properly if you're still interested in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't detailed enough, but in general you'll want to set classes on the specific li elements as needed.

For example:

```
<ul>
<li class="first winter thirty-one">January</li>
<li class="winter">February</li>
<li class="spring thirty-one">March</li>
<li class="spring">April</li>
<li class="spring thirty-one">May</li>
<li class="summer">June</li>
<li class="summer schools-out thirty-one">July</li>
<li class="summer schools-out thirty-one">August</li>
<li class="fall">September</li>
<li class="fall thirty-one">October</li>
<li class="fall">November</li>
<li class="last winter thirty-one">December</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I need to know how to do it with jquery. See last answers comments for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to access a specific index of elements.

The `:eq()` selector can access a single index:

```
$('li:eq(1)')
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

The `.nextAll()` function returns all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements:

```
$('li:eq(2)').nextAll();
```

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

The `.prevAll()` works the same way but returns the previous siblings:

```
$('li:eq(2)').prevAll();
```

http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.filter()` method to filter down your selection.

```
$('li').filter(':nth-child(n+3)').addClass('className');
```

Now, anything meets this criteria, will receive the class attribute. In your example, 3rd, 4th and 5th li will receive it.